# How to effectively search through MySQL DB with multiple searcheable columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a table with 60 boolean (TINYINT(1)) searcheable columns. User has possibility of using any subset of the given columns as search condition. Based on that I cannot create a good index for my needs. I was wondering if I can create another column (concat_col) of type BIT(60) that would be concatenation of the searchable columns, i.e.

```
Table_A:
id   |col1|col2|...|col60|concat_col
9999 | 1  | 0  |...|  1  |10...1
```

I could then create a good index for it (on concat_col) but there is one problem - how do I create a query for it?

Please see this example written in pseudo code:

Standard version (This would obviously work fine):

```
SQL = SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE col1=1 AND col60=1
```

My version ('*' is wildcard because it is not '1' neither '0'):

```
SQL = SELECT * FROM Table_a WHERE concat_col = '1*...1'
```

Is there any possibility of solving this problem effectively? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'll give you an idea since you're on a good way yourself. You have 60 columns. First column is 2 to the power of 0. Second is 2 to the power of 1. Third is 2 to the power of 3. And so on until you reach 60. Therefore, you can describe any combination of columns with a single number.

Comment: @N.B. Thank you for your help. However, I think I won't be able to achieve what I really need. In fact, I will be able to describe any cobination of columns with a number but I need to ignore all columns except the ones I am interested in (col1 and col60 in this case). All other columns's values are not important. Is it doable with your idea?

Comment: Yes, it's doable :) imagine if you wanted to inspect column 1 and 3 only. The number describing that combination is decimal 5. 1st column = 1 (2 pow 0 = 1), second column is skipped (0), third column is 2 pow 2 = 4. 4 + 1 = 5.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But this assumes that all other bits are zeros (0). What if they are not? If i.e. column 2 is also 1 then 1+2+4=7. It means 7 should also match my query.

Comment: No. The column you don't want to refer to is always 0. The column you want to refer to is always 1. Then, when you line up all 60 columns, you get a stream of 1s and 0s which is a binary number. That means you can convert that binary number into a decimal one. The decimal number can be indexed then.

Comment: I don't agree. I think your query is: SQL = SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE col1=1 AND col60=1 AND col2=0 AND col4=0 ... AND col60 = 0. However, my query is: SQL = SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE col1=1 AND col60=1. Am I missing something?:)

Comment: This is a two-part "problem" if you will. First is to index a range of columns. That's why you use bit-masking to be able to have a good index. That gives you the list of columns you want to inspect (eg. 5 = column 1 and column 3). Then comes the value inspection. You inspect values and you do a lesser scan because index reduces the amount of rows you'll be inspecting. So you end up with `SELECT * FROM table WHERE big_integer_value = 5 AND col1 = 0 AND col3 = 1`;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32068/discussion-between-flexjack-and-n-b)

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
SQL = SELECT * FROM Table_a WHERE concat_col REGEXP '^1[0-9a-zA-Z]{58}1$'
```

Comment: Thanks, I will. Will it be effective and use index? It is my main concern.

Comment: Yes, it will be done much faster if you add index, which will consume some space and memory on disck/ram

Comment: No, it won't. The indexes will have awful cardinality. Full table scan will be performed every time.